# Water movement in variable diameter bent capillary?

Tags: water, surface-tension, capillary-action, adhesion

So, I recently learned that if a capillary tube is bent in an upside down U shape, the meniscus formed will be convex (towards the ground). Furthermore, the height (shown as h) traveled by the water in the first capillary, is the same as the distance the water travels in the bent capillary tube (so, a distance of h).

From these facts, I have another question now regarding the flow of water through the capillary.

Imagine a capillary tube, as drawn in the picture, that has an **increasing** radius as it approaches the ground. If the radius begins to increase before the *h*, will a meniscus fail to form? And so, would water, because of adhesion, trickle down the glass (whether the surface tension prevents it from dripping off or not)?

Or would a meniscus still form, but at a distance less than *h* as a result of the increasing radius (which, from Jurin's law, means that water would not travel as far by capillary action, as a result of the larger diameter). So, this would mean that water would never trickle to the edge of the tube?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Not completely sure about answer, but I would say that the water cannot travel further if the tubes diameter grows. At the end, tube B looks like a perpetual motion machine of first kind.

Comment: Yeah, you're correct about the diameter. As the diameter increases, the distance water can travel, decreases. But I'm wondering how the water will react, and how the meniscus will look. Or would a meniscus not even form? In that case, what would happen, and what would it look like?

Comment: The water flow should gradually decrease...but after a certain point the volume of water balance disturbs ....
are you still working on movement of water in bent capillary tube .I would like to discuss this with you.